# How to get product name in magento?

Tags: magento, product, catalog

I am trying to get **only product name** using the product id.

I have tried the below:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(PRODUCT_ID);
$product->getName();
```

It load the whole resource object and than we can get the name using `$product->getName()` but I need only single name so we can reduce the extra overheads.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', PRODUCT_ID)->load();
```

It also load the resource object.

is there any easiest way to get the product name( for exa. 'Test product') without loading the resource object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getAttributeRawValue()` With this you can get the attribute value of your product :

```
$attribute_value = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue(PRODUCT_ID, 'attribute_code');
```

Answer (score 1):

*Try this,hope it's work for you.*

Try this :

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product'); then
$product->getName();
$product->getId();
```

You can try this for product :

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$current_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass store value as well to get product attribute directly from resource model.
You can get store id by using this code:- `Mage::app()->getStore().`

**So the final query will  be :-**

```
 $attribute_value = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue(PRODUCT_ID,'attribute_code',Mage::app()->getStore());
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.